# Creating a .bat file to run a python virtual environment in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, python-venv

I've tried several methods found while searching for an answer, such as:

```
start venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1

run venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1

call venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1

cd .venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

All of the above simply opened the Activate.ps1 file, instead of running the virtual environment.

My goal here is to have the batch file open powershell with the virtual environment already running, instead of just opening the file.

Edit:

Using `powershell .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`, the powershell starts but doesn't appear to actually start the venv.

[Powershell after running the .bat with the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVVyC.png)

[Screenshot of a batch file compiled with commands that work individually in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zykc9.png)

[Screenshot of the commands from the batch file working when input manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qbal.png)

[Screenshot of what happens when running the above batch file (it opens activate.ps1 in a text file as well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8PQR.png)

Comment: Because `ps1` files do not have a default application associated with them to launch them on `start` or via double click (for good reason). So start powershell with the scripts. `powershell .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and when I run it I'm not getting the (venvname) indicating that the environment is active. 

I've edited the post with your solution and a screenshot of what happens when I use it.

Comment: Have you adjusted your execution policy settings? `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` or a little more risky `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` (the latter requires admin rights to launch, anyway)

Comment: What should the batch file look like with this addition?

Comment: This is not exactly what you asked but another way would be to make a ps1 script containing `invoke-expression -Command .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` and execute it from a powershell (with absolute paths instead and adding those scripts location to the Path, I use it to activate different global venvs from any powershell "location")